# Determine values of $ \ p , \ q \ $ if we have$ \ (3 \mathbb{Z}+1) \cap (4 \mathbb{Z}+2) =(p \mathbb{Z}+q) \ $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Determine values of $ \ p , \ q \ $ if we have $ \ (3 \mathbb{Z}+1) \cap (4 \mathbb{Z}+2) =(p \mathbb{Z}+q) \ $

Also use set comprehension notation for $ \ (r \mathbb{Z}+t) \cup 3 \mathbb{Z} \ , \ \ r \neq t  , \ \ r,t \in \mathbb{Z} $

**Answer:**
$ (3 \mathbb{Z}+1) \cap (4 \mathbb{Z}+2) =(p \mathbb{Z}+q) \\ \Rightarrow \{a \in \mathbb{Z} | a=3k+1 \} \cap \{b \in \mathbb{Z} | b=4k'+2 \}=(p \mathbb{Z}+q) \\ \Rightarrow \{a \in \mathbb{Z} | a=b \} =(p \mathbb{Z}+q)$

**But I can't proceed further .**

**If there is any help ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).
Since $3$ and $4$ are coprime, the set of equations:
$$x = 1 \mod 3 \\ x = 2 \mod 4$$

has a solution which is unique modulo $3\cdot4 = 12$

By observing we can find that the solution is $x = 10$, and since it is unique modulo $12$ we can deduce that $(3 \mathbb{Z}+1) \cap (4 \mathbb{Z}+2) =(12 \mathbb{Z}+10)$

Answer (score 1):

Without observing, there's a formula to solve a system of two linear congruences modulo coprime integers $a, b$, which relies on a *Bézout's identity* between these integers:
$$ua+vb=1.$$
Such a relation can always be found with the *extended Euclidean algorithm* (which is not necessary here: $\;4-3=1$).
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv r\pmod a\\x\equiv s\pmod b\end{cases}\iff x\equiv sua+rvb\pmod{ab}.$$
In the present case, you obtain $\;\color{red}{x\equiv -2 \mod{12}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$3\Bbb Z+1 = \{...,-2, 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,...\} \\ 4\Bbb Z+2 = \{...,-2,2,6,10,14,18,22,...\}\\3\Bbb Z+1\cap4\Bbb Z+2=\{...,-2,10,22,...\}$

So...